# two problems on implementing react without create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a simple react app to practice creating stuffs without dependencies provided by create-react-app (webpack - babel ....)

I am faced with two problems

this is the code:

**HTML**

```
 <html>
  <head><head>
  <body>
    <div id="App"> </div>
    <script type="module" src="script.js" ></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = () => {
    class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return(
          <div className="App">
            <p>any paragraph</p>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

   ReactDom.render(App, document.getElementById('App'))
}
```

**The first problem is:**

Nothing is happening when adding the `type` attribute to the `script` tag and set its value to `"module"`, nothing works at all, as if js engine could not access the script!!

**The second problem:**

After removing `type="module"`, it works but with a console error  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

**So why these two problems happens and how to solve them??**

Comment: You need to transpile your JSX.

Comment: ^^ (or not use JSX, but...JSX is really handy)

Comment: ok i got that, what about the first problem

Comment: Since you have no module syntax (`import`/`export`) in your JS, why would you expect including it as a module to be useful?

Comment: @MTCoster i used them but nothing worked, so why i am ask the question!!

Comment: If you intend to use them in your code, you should include them in your examples here as well

Comment: I just said above that literally nothing worked after adding the attribute, it is like the interpreter could not access the script at all, that is it

Answer (score 0):

Try loading `script.js` last. That is, after `react-dom` is loaded.

Comment: You have incorrect html tag in your html code, correct that so it starts with `<`.

Comment: thank you but this was not the problem, it was just a problem of copy and paste, still good catch!!

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use JSX directly in a browser. You will need to include babel for that: add this line before script.js: <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>. Also you will need to change the type to 'text/babel' for script.js. Lastly, ReactDom.render(App, document.getElementById('App')) should be corrected to ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('App'))

Comment: ```<script src="script.js"  type="text/babel"></script>```

nothing worked at all, it was like adding the ```type="module"```

Comment: Did you add babel.min.js before script.js?